# How do you add only a top and bottom border to a TextButton in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you add only a top and bottom border to a TextButton in flutter/dart?

```dart
TextButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Button'),
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the `TextButton` with  a `Container` and set the `decoration`:

```dart
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Button'),
      ),
    )
```

[image]